# EMR Hive connect to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr

I'm going crazy.

I'm trying to connect to a file on S3 in Hive (on an EMR cluster) and I keep getting an error

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_table_segments (
    >     ...columns
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    > LOCATION 's3://<path>'
    > TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Unable to create path: s3://<path>)
```

I've been following the suggestions [here](https://sysadmins.co.za/aws-import-csv-data-from-s3-to-dynamodb/), [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb/) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html) and it's all the same thing. Am I missing some sort of authentication for S3 that all these articles just neglect to mention?

Comment: The EMR nodes would need access to the CSV file in the S3 bucket, of course. That's something you supply via permissions on the relevant IAM role you supply when creating the cluster. Also, when you map a Hive table to a location in Amazon S3, do not map it to the root path of the bucket, s3://mybucket (per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html).

Comment: Have you changed any default configurations on EMR? What is your value for hive.metastore.warehouse.dir in hive-site.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into this issue. In my case, that s3 path had a file and a folder with identical names. Renaming the file (I meant the folder to be the contents of the table) solved the issue.